# For row-level or page-level, how to undo a compression in SQL Server? With SQL command and/or GUI Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms, compression

We want to compress a table, using SQL statements like the samples below. And, just in case any issue happened after the compression, and we need to roll back to the last good point. How do we do it?

**Our Question:**

- With the below compressing SQL statements, how do we undo the compression?
- See the "Additional Information" below.
  Tentatively, I believe the GUI Management Studio generates wrong SQLs for undoing compression on an index. Am I seeing the same symptoms as everyone else?

**Details:**

The sample SQL statements for row-level compression:

```sql
-- To row-level compress the table
USE [database-under-test]
ALTER TABLE [schema].[sales_order] REBUILD PARTITION = ALL
WITH 
(DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW
)

-- To row-level compress one index, and
-- the other indices of the table are similar
USE [database-under-test]
ALTER INDEX [SALES_ORDER_CREATED_AT] ON [schema].[sales_order] REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH (
PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, 
DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW
)


-- Compression statements are similar for the other indices of the table
-- ...
```

**Additional Information:**

Tentatively, I believe the GUI Management Studio generates wrong SQLs for undoing compression on an index.

For example, with the "Storage Management" wizard, we set compression to "None" and it gets:

```sql
ALTER INDEX [SALES_ORDER_UPDATED_AT] ON [schema].[sales_order] REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH (
PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
)
```

Noticed there is no `DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE` in the statement, and the index still shows row-level compressed after executing the command.

Am I seeing the same symptoms as everyone else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do we undo the compression?

rebuild table or index with **DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/disable-compression-on-a-table-or-index?view=sql-server-ver16#TsqlProcedure

Comment: Tentatively, I believe the GUI Management Studio generates wrong SQLs for undoing compression on an index, e.g., it gets `ALTER INDEX [SALES_ORDER_UPDATED_AT] ON [msab_magento].[sales_order] REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)`. Noticed there is no `DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE` in the statement, and the index still shows row-level compressed after executing the command. Am I seeing the same symptoms as everyone else?

Comment: By the way, in my system under test, the Management Studio is in version `13.0.16106.4`, and the SQL Server 14 is in version `(SP2-GDR) (KB4505220) - 13.0.5101.9 (X64)`.

Comment: @James Well, don't do this with the GUI. But if you must, make sure you [turn on index and compression options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VRQo.png) in Tools / Options.